# Notice: Undefined variable: i in F:\wamp\www\search\search.php on line 20 and

Tags: php, mysql, database

I tried to solve this error but failed. I am trying to create a search engine like google but there are 2 errors which are as follows:-

**error no. 1**

```
Notice: Undefined variable: i in F:\wamp\www\searchwall\search.php on line 20
```

And here is the **error no.2**

```
Warning: mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in F:\wamp\www\searchwall\search.php on line 31
```

and ***here is the code and file name is search.php ***

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
 <head>
  <title>
  SearchWall search 
  </title>
 </head>
 <body>
     <h2>WELCOME TO SEARCHWALL!!</h2>
   <form action ='./search.php' method= 'get'>
     <input type='text' name='r' size ='50' value='<?php echo $_GET['r']; ?>' />
     <input type='submit' value='search' />
   </form>
   <hr />
   <?php
    $r = $_GET['r'];
    $terms = explode(" ", $r);
    $query = "SELECT * FROM searches WHERE ";
    foreach ($terms as $each) {
     $i++;
      if ($i == 1)
        $query .= "keywords LIKE '%$each%' ";
      else
        $query .= "OR keywords LIKE '%$each%' ";
    }
    // connect
    mysql_connect("localhost","","");
    mysql_select_db("search");

      $query = mysql_query($query);
      $numrows = mysql_num_rows($query);
      if ($numrows > 0 ){
         while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
          $id = $row['id'];
          $title = $row['title'];
          $description = $row['description'];
          $keywords = $row['keywords'];
          $link = $row['link'];

           echo"<h2><a href='$link'>$title</a></h2>
           $description<br /><br />";
         }
      }
      else
        echo "No results found for \"<b>$r</b>\"";
    // disconnect
    mysql_close();
   ?>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: and yeah please rewrite the code. THANKS

Comment: Undefined is undefined. (I.e. the variable `$i` is read before it has been assigned a non-undefined value.) The second error reported is because the SQL call failed. (I.e. false was returned, and false cannot be used with the subsequent functions to access the [non-]result.) Neither of these issues are uncommon and searching for them will lead to *many* duplicates.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You aren't initializing `$i` before referencing it. Just initialize it to `0`, and you should be fine.

```
$i = 0;
foreach ($terms as $each) {
    $i++;
    # etc.
```

Comment: still this error is showing up Warning: mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in F:\wamp\www\searchwall\search.php on line 32

Answer (score 0):

First you need to defined $i before the loop and second you should not write the **WHERE** before make sure there is things to search or you should keep it WHERE 1=1

```
// $query = "SELECT * FROM searches WHERE ";
$query = "SELECT * FROM searches";
if(count($terms) > 0)
   $query .= " WHERE ";
$i = 0;
foreach ($terms as $each) {
   $i++;
   ...
```